# How to get C-Knobs on M-Audio Oxygen 25 to work with GarageBand

Tags: osx, garageband, m-audio

My daughter got a M-Audio Oxygen 25.  We have OSX 10.11.6 and GarageBand 10.1.2.  I downloaded the latest [M-Audio drivers](http://www.m-audio.com/support/download/software/directlink-for-garagebandx-v.1.1.1).  Before the drivers, we could only play the keys, the pitch and mod controls, and the pads.  But the transport buttons did not work neither did the knobs or the fader.  Once we installed the driver, the fader and the transport buttons worked.

However, the Knobs (C1 through C8) don't seem to do anything.  I found this helpful post https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2744706?start=0&tstart=0 and I have tried using preset 10 but it makes no difference.  We've tried a bunch of different instruments.  My hope is that we can make these knobs control the instrument properties such as EQ, reverb, etc.

Is there a way to make the Knobs work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research, and came to the conclusion that you **can't** assign the control knobs to any of the native parameters in GB(it doesn't allow **MIDI Mapping**). Your only option if your daughter really wants to control EQ and other things with the Oxygen's contol knobs, is to use third-party plugins with MIDI assignable parameters.

> References
>   [Apple Discussions - "Assigning midi knobs to garageband on M-AUDIO OZONE"](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3319459?start=0&tstart=0)
>   [M-Audio Community "Can't get Garageband to map controls on Axiom 49"](http://community.m-audio.com/m-audio/topics/cant-get-garageband-to-map-controls-on-axiom-49)
>   [M-Audio Community - "can i assign controls on my v25 in garageband?"](http://community.m-audio.com/m-audio/topics/cant-get-garageband-to-map-controls-on-axiom-49)
>   [TalkBass.com - "mapping midi in garageband"](https://www.talkbass.com/threads/mapping-midi-in-garageband.236045/)
>   [Transport Buttons Help(alludes to problems)](http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/How_To/en398033)